# Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Decimal' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable' when attempting to use in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SampleComponent: View {
  @Binding var value: Decimal

  var body: some View {
    return Text("\(value)")
  }
}
```

Gives me the error:

> Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Decimal' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'

This works fine in a playground though:

```
import Foundation

var d: Decimal = 4.5
print("\(d)")
```

Any idea what's going on or how to fix it?

Comment: Not at all clear how the "as duplicate" answers this question.

Answer (score 26):

Not exactly sure why it gives this error, but one solution is to cast it to a String:

```
Text("\(value)" as String)
```

Comment: Man, I've been looking for a solution to this generics problem for a while now... I tried a lot of protocol conformance and other combinations, but it never worked. I'd still love to understand why doing this force-cast fixes the issue though...

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to cast a value that isn't a string. The as String method did not work for me, however this did:
Text("\(String(describing: value)")