# I need to limit a variable to 1 decimal point

Tags: swiftui, rounding

I have a view that shows results of several calculations.
The results appear with multiple decimal points that the user do not need.
I'm struggling with this but unable to achieve desired result.

```
    Section("Associated values") {
            if diagnos.valorasociado1 != "" {
                Text("\(diagnos.valorasociado1, specifier: "%.1f")")
```

Tried this line above but i get this error : Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:specifier:)' requires that 'String' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'

```
    if diagnos.valorasociado1 != "" {
                Text (diagnos.valorasociado1, specifier: "%.1f")
                }
```

this line gets me this error : Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625816/instance-method-appendinterpolation-requires-that-decimal-conform-to-forma

Comment: adding "as String" gets me 'Extra argument 'specifier' in call

Comment: Why are your calculations returning a string value instead of a numeric value? Change that and perform the formatting in the ui, that is my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`valorasociado1` is clearly a string, the formatter with specifier is for numeric values.

What you can do is to convert the string to `Double` and then use the native Swift(UI) formatter syntax

```
if !diagnos.valorasociado1.isEmpty,
    let value = Double(diagnos.valorasociado1) {
        Text(value.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1))))
}
```

Comment: valorasociado is a string because is a combination of a string and an interpolated double.    diagnos.valorasociado2 = "Anion Gap(alb): \(viewModel.gapcoAlb)" If i could limit the variable to two decimal points that would solve the issue but i do not know how to do it

Comment: I'll add .formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(1))) to each number variable

Comment: The integer in `fractionLength(1)` specifies the number of decimal places.